# How to create INDEX for large data in ORACLE (150 million)

Tags: oracle11g

I want to create an Index for some table.
I tried manually by writing index syntax like

```
create index index_name on table
```

with this I tried, but it is taking so much time for large data (150 million).

I heard that we can create index in (back end) the server also like "index.sh". I don't know exactly about this.

Comment: What is a crore, and why is 15 of them significant?

Comment: @Adam Musch: 1 crore = 100 lakhs.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I think when someone advised you to "create index in(back end)", they might have meant "create it as a background task", may be submit a job during off peak hours.

If your table is large, you should consider partitioning and then create local/global index partitions. Without knowing about the application (Data warehouse/OLTP), type of data, table structures and how it is accessed, it is difficult to come up with the appropriate solution.

Also, If you are trying to build an index on a really large table, you should [Consider Creating Indexes with NOLOGGING](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17120/indexes002.htm#ADMIN11719). It comes with it's own gotchas( you have to take a back up after the index is created), so you should see if it makes sense in your case.